# ESPI : <input type "hidden" value="SOME_URL"> validation fails

Tags: java, security, esapi

I am using ESPI security for my Java web application. There is one input type

when I submit the form, the validation fails.

is there any special care should be take for this kind of value?

Comment: Can you share a little piece of code showing your problem?

Comment: when My url parameter is like prodref="product" it is not working but if I remove o or d, it is working...Strange!!